# GCP Dataflow ReadFromKafka creating a lot of connections

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are creating Dataflow job using Python to read data from Kafka (Amazon MSK, 6 brokers, 5 partitions topic). Dataflow job is deployed in a VPC that has a Cloud NAT (single public IP) and this IP is fully allowed on out on AWS side.

I turned on `commit_offset_in_finalize=True` and set `group.id`. Also disabled `enable.auto.commit`.

In worker logs I can see that there are following warnings spawning all the time:

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-Reader-2_offset_consumer_452577593_my-group-id-695, groupId=Reader-2_offset_consumer_452577593_my-group-id] Connection to node -3 (b-3-public.some-cluster-name.amazonaws.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-Reader-2_offset_consumer_1356187250_my-group-id-640, groupId=Reader-2_offset_consumer_1356187250_my-group-id] Bootstrap broker b-3-public.some-cluster-name.amazonaws.com:YYYY(id: -3 rack: null) disconnected`

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 300000ms expired before the position for partition my-topic-4 could be determined`

And also errors:

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 300000ms expired before successfully committing offsets {my-topic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=13610611, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}`

There are not many events, like 5/sec so there is no load at all.

I logged into VM that hosts my job and run `toolbox` to see what is happening.

I noticed that there are a log of connection being created all the time to reach Kafka. Having all the parameter as below it is 100-200 estabilished connections. Earlir it was above 300-400 hundred and SYN_SENT connections were piling up to 2000 connection in total making worker machine unable to connect to Kafka at all.

Any ideas what is causing this many connections?

Piepeline looks as follows:

```
with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    (
        pipeline
        |   'Read record from Kafka' >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config={
                    'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
                    'group.id': 'my-group-id',
                    'default.api.timeout.ms' : '300000',
                    'enable.auto.commit' : 'false',
                    'security.protocol': 'SSL',
                    'ssl.truststore.location': truststore_location,
                    'ssl.truststore.password': truststore_password,
                    'ssl.keystore.location': keystore_location,
                    'ssl.keystore.password': keystore_password,
                    'ssl.key.password': key_password
                },
                topics=['my-topic'],
                with_metadata=True,
                commit_offset_in_finalize=True
            )

        |   'Format message element to name tuple' >> ParDo(
                FormatMessageElement(logger, corrupted_events_table, bq_table_name)
            )

        |   'Get events row' >> ParDo(
                BigQueryEventRow(logger)
            )

        |   'Write events to BigQuery' >> io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=bq_table_name,
                dataset=bq_dataset,
                project=project,
                schema=event_table_schema,
                write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                create_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters,
                insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ALWAYS
            )
    )
```

And here are start parameter (removed standard parameter):

```
python3 streaming_job.py \
(...)
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --experiments=use_runner_v2 \
    --number_of_worker_harness_threads=1 \
    --experiments=no_use_multiple_sdk_containers \
    --sdk_container_image=${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
    --sdk_harness_container_image_overrides=".*java.*,${DOCKER_IMAGE_JAVA}"

    
gcloud dataflow jobs run streaming_job \
(...)
    --worker-machine-type=n2-standard-4 \
    --num-workers=1 \
    --max-workers=10
```

I tried modifying:

`number_of_worker_harness_threads` - less threads, less connections

`no_use_multiple_sdk_containers` - one SDK container per worker, less connections from worker

more resources - more SDK container, more connections

`default.api.timeout.ms` - by increasing it, number of timeouts was reduced

And ended up with parameters as above. And still 100-200 connections and ReadFromKafka is working like crazy when other stages have nothing to do

[image]

Comment: Does this behavior only happen when you are enabling `use_runner_v2`? Can you please compare between legacy and Runner v2, so we don't look at the wrong direction?

Comment: Right now I am unable to compare it with legacy because I need `sdk_harness_container_image_overrides` option to provide prebuild image with certificates for Java. I would need to create my own environment without SSL. When I will find time I will try to but now that's all I've got.

Comment: Hi @fl0r3k, can you try to connect after increasing the timeout?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Yes I did as described. I set it to 5 minutes.
@BrunoVolpato I tried using legacy runner but I am unable to. `ReadFromKafka` is "cross language transform"
`ValueError: This pipeline contains cross language transforms, which require runner v2.`

Comment: Hi @fl0r3k, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: @ShipraSarkar Thank you for your advice. Actually I searched the Issuea Tracket and I found issue about number of connection to Kafka. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232907065 . Maybe I will try also with a support.

Comment: The newer version of Beam SDK (like March) still creates a lot of connections but at least not spamming them like crazy. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (TimeoutException: Timeout of 300000ms expired before the position for partition my-topic-4 could be determined) and solved it by dropping the

```
--experiments=use_runner_v2
```

option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I need certificates and for that custom Java docker image is required. Only `use_runner_v2` supports that.